# Tetrahedron side lengths from vertices (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

I'm trying to calculate the side lengths of a tetrahedron from its vertices using NumPy, but the best I can come up with is a bit of a tangle:

```
import numpy as np
V = np.array([[ 1,  1,  1], [-1, -1,  1], [ 1, -1, -1], [-1,  1, -1]])
vertex_pair_indexes = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]])
np.squeeze(np.linalg.norm((diff(V[vertex_pair_indexes], axis=1)), axis=2))
```

Can I refactor this more naturally and avoid the `np.squeeze()` call? Is there a way, short of using `itertools.combinations` to generate all pairs of vertex coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can simplify the calculation:

```
In [42]: vertex_pair_indexes
Out[42]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3]])

In [43]: first = vertex_pair_indexes[:, 0]

In [44]: second = vertex_pair_indexes[:, 1]

In [45]: np.linalg.norm(V[first] - V[second], axis=-1)
Out[45]: 
array([ 2.82842712,  2.82842712,  2.82842712,  2.82842712,  2.82842712,
        2.82842712])
```

You could, as you suggested, use `itertools.combinations` to generate `vertex_pair_indexes`, but if you are only interested in a tetrahedron, you might just as well hardwire the required vertices with `first = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2])` and `second = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3])`.

---

Alternatively, if you don't mind a dependency on scipy, you can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html):

```
In [70]: from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

In [71]: pdist(V)
Out[71]: 
array([ 2.82842712,  2.82842712,  2.82842712,  2.82842712,  2.82842712,
        2.82842712])
```